# I need twitter dataset for last 3-4 months relating to any company/ comodity for stock price prediction

Tags: sentiment-analysis, stock

I need twitter dataset for last 3-4 months relating to any company/ commodity for performing sentiment analysis and thereby stock price prediction.
But the twitter API only goes back upto 10-12 days.The code that I've prepared works well but I need more dataset to reach a reliable conclusion.I can't wait for 3-4 months since I've to submit the project soon.
If anyone knows any link where I can find some dataset or if anyone has it,
Please let me know.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably could check out these discussions ([1](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1545/twitter-open-datasets),[2](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/7390/historical-twitter-data)) and also this [site](http://followthehashtag.com/datasets/nasdaq-100-companies-free-twitter-dataset).

Comment: No problems. Is it sufficient?

Comment: Yes , it seems sufficient for now. Thanks again :)